# Progress bar getting stuck

Tags: android, dialog, android-progressbar

I'm implementing a custom dialog with the library [MaterialDialog by afollestad](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs), and I've tried to use it to show a ProgressDialog. There are to ways of doing it, calling .show() on a new MaterialDialog class, or making a variable for the class and call .build() to have the possibility of dismiss or show the dialog from another method. The problem is that when I use .show the progressbar run smoothly but I can dismiss it, when I call the .build() method the progressbar freezes, but I can dismiss or cancel.

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity implements HomeMvpView {

    MaterialDialog materialDialog;
```

Custom dialog

```
public void showProgressDialog(String title, String content, String positiveText, String neutralText, String negativeText){

        String carrefour_blue_color = "#" + Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));

        materialDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .progress(true, 0)
                .progressIndeterminateStyle(true)
                .cancelable(false)
                .canceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                .titleColorRes(R.color.blue)
                .contentColor(Color.parseColor(blue_color)) // notice no 'res' postfix for literal color
                .dividerColorRes(R.color.blue_focused)
                .backgroundColorRes(R.color.white)
                .positiveColorRes(R.color.green)
                .neutralColorRes(R.color.gray)
                .negativeColorRes(R.color.red)
                .widgetColorRes(R.color.blue)
                .buttonRippleColorRes(R.color.yellow)
                .titleGravity(GravityEnum.CENTER)
                .contentGravity(GravityEnum.CENTER)
                .btnStackedGravity(GravityEnum.START)
                .itemsGravity(GravityEnum.END)
                .buttonsGravity(GravityEnum.END)
                .title((title != null ? title : null))
                .content((content != null ? content : null))
                .positiveText((positiveText != null ? positiveText : null))
                .neutralText((neutralText != null ? neutralText : null))
                .negativeText((negativeText != null ? negativeText : null))
                .showListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }
                })
                .cancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }
                })
                .dismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }
                })
                .build();


    }
```

Later I will use materialDialog.dismiss... Why the animation kept freezes.

Comment: You didnt dismiss your dialog in this method. public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)... I suppose you should be dismissing your dialog here which is unimplemented

Comment: The problem is that the progress bar doesn't moves